# How to add an online account that is not listed by default?

Tags: 18.04, online-accounts

I would like to add an online account provider that is not listed by default in Ubuntu 18.04 (www.clarodrive.com).
Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Add it to what? What have you tried?

Comment: I would like to use clarodrive.com in the same way as I use google drive, as a unit, from the file manager. Is this possible?
Thanks @waltinator !

Comment: I'm a basic user, sorry I haven't tried anything. Any help is great!